# Traversing some cells in a P*Q Grid in c

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I have a M*N array which I have to traverse.There are M*N cells(starting from 1 to M*N). There will be an input n and according to that I will have to move to a next possible cell. **A person at cell n can only traverse at his left, right or front cell**. I will have to choose a position randomly and display it.

My sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int row,col,n,p;
    int array[3];  
    printf("\nEnter row and columns:");
    scanf("%d""%d",&row,&col);
    printf("\nEnter a position:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    array[3]={n-1,n+1,n-row); //three possible movements(although I have used 1D array here,n determines the cell position(say: any value from 1 to 25), I have treated the array positions as 2D. For example: if n=7, then for a 5*5 array, possible movements are cells 6,8 and 2
    p= array[ rand() % 3 ]+1;  //choosing a next random position
    printf("\nnext cell is %d",p);
}
```

But there is a problem. Lets consider a scenario for 5*5 array:

```
from cell 1, I can only move to right.
from cell 2,3,4, I can move to both left and right cells.
from cell 5, I can only move left.
from cell 6,11,16,21, I can move only right and upwards.
from cell 25,20,15,10, I can move at only left and upwards
```

Now for the above cells,the above program may generate wrong positions(garbage values like negative or greater than 25). This is just a general case or 5*5 array. But how will I handle this type of conditions in any M*N array. Is there any rule that I can apply in the above program to get correct output?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you solve it with `m` and `n` seperately instead calculating that with `m*n`.
If the board is in size `N*M` (`N` rows, `M` columns):
if the current row is `n (0<=n<=N-1)` and the current column is `m (0<=m<=M-1)`:

```
if n==0 you can only move right.
else if n==N-1 you can only move left.
else both.
if m==0 you can only move down.
else if m==M-1 you can only move up.
else both.
```

And by that you can know how you can move from array[n][m];